# Flash and javascript ExternalInterface safety

Tags: javascript, flash, actionscript-3, security, externalinterface

Is it safe to share data between flash and javascript using ExternalInterface? I'm building a game where I want to pass scores to js, not sure if this is safe enough.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing is safe.  Anything you pass to JavaScript could be easily retrieved just by using a browser's developer console, by overriding the function called by ExternalInterface and intercepting the arguments.